# Include string and cell value in sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple workbook with sheets for 3 different websites I may buy things from.  I want to have the tab name update as I edit the worksheets.  The worksheet name would be website name + total of all items (cell C27)

This is the macro as I have it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B27")) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Amazon " + ActiveSheet.Range("B27")
    End If
End Sub
```

I get the runtime error '13':
Type mismatch

I know this is because I'm combining 2 different types a string and a value, but I'm not too familiar with the syntax of VBA to be able to fix it.

If I leave out the website name, it works perfectly.

What is the easiest fix?

Comment: & not +, What is in range B27?  There is a limit to length and some special chars to I believe, also try, .value after the range, as your trying to combine a range and a string

Comment: You might also try replacing the '+' with '&' as not sure if Excel allows the former.

Comment: `"Amazon " + cstr(ActiveSheet.Range("B27"))` for type mismatch. Put CSTR otherwise if the cells contains an error value you will still get type mismatch irrespective of `+` or `&`. Also  Length should be <= 32.

Comment: Both of those solutions work! Thanks everyone!

Comment: You should definitely go with the ampersand method, here and in general. Although both work in this situation, the & is meant for concatenation, whereas the + is meant for addition.

Comment: @SJR VBA (not Excel) will treat the `+` operator as a string concatenation operator *if all operands are strings*. The `&` operator implicitly converts all non-string operands into strings before concatenating, that's why it works. Looking at the code, IMO the OP would benefit much more in understanding what implicit things VBA is doing behind their back, than just knowing to use the `&` operator to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> ActiveSheet.Name = "Amazon " + ActiveSheet.Range("B27")
> ```

`ActiveSheet.Name` is a `String`. So is the `"Amazon"` literal. I presume cell `$B$27` on the `ActiveSheet` contains a numeric value; the `+` operator being the *addition* operator, VBA is throwing a *type mismatch* because it doesn't know how to *add* a string with a number, as you can easily reproduce in the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G):

```
?"foo" + 42
'type mismatch
```

Replacing the `+` operator with the *string concatenation* operator `&` fixes the symptom, and "works":

```
?"foo" & 42
'foo42
```

However you need to think of what's *really* going on, and fix the *problem*, not just the *symptom*: when you use the *string concatenation* operator, VBA implicitly converts all operands to strings. You can make that conversion explicit with the `CStr` function:

```
?"foo" & CStr(42)
'foo42, this time without implicit conversions
```

But `ActiveSheet.Range("B27")` is an *object* - a `Range` object reference:

```
?TypeName(ActiveSheet.Range("B27"))
Range
```

There's yet another implicit operation going on here: it's not the object reference you're converting to a string (implicitly or explicitly), it's the value of its *default member*. If you look at the `Range` object in the *Object Browser* (F2), you'll notice it has a hidden `_Default` property:

[image: Range.[_Default] in the VBE Object Browser]

That default property is apparently implemented in such a way that it gets/sets the `Range.Value`; this is why this code compiles:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B27") = 42
```

As does this code:

```
Dim foo As Long
foo = ActiveSheet.Range("B27")
```

Without the *default member* implicitly "redirecting" the call to the `Value`, these would be illegal, because you can't assign an object reference without using the `Set` keyword, and you can't assign an object reference to a value either.

Notice the difference between `Range("B27")` here:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B27")) Is Nothing Then
```

Versus here:

```
ActiveSheet.Name = "Amazon " + ActiveSheet.Range("B27")
```

The former is the `Range` object, the latter is its `Value`. Also notice that `Range("B27")` is implicitly referring to the `ActiveSheet`, so this:

```
Range("B27")
```

Is exactly the same as this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B27")
```

There's no reason to not explicitly qualify it with `ActiveSheet` everywhere. In fact, just looking at any random 100 Stack Overflow questions in the [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) tag, qualifying all `Range` calls with a `Worksheet` object is going to save you a lot of problems down the line.

Hence, the *explicit* way to write your handler is as follows - note that a valid sheet name must be 32 characters or less, so you need to truncate the name if the concatenated string is longer than that. And since two sheets can't have the same name, you need to do *something* if the truncated string results in a sheet name that's already in the workbook:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("B27")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Name = Left$("Amazon " & CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("B27").Value), 32)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Could not rename worksheet '" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'."
    End If
End Sub
```

And at that point it doesn't matter whether you use the `&` or the `+` operator, because the `+` operator works perfectly fine to concatenate strings... when all operands *are* strings - except for consistency and readability, you will definitely want to prefer using the `&` operator when concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions listed in the comments work!

I can replace the '+' with '&' OR use the cstr(ActiveSheet.Range("B27")) method.

Comment: You should definitely go with the ampersand method, here and in general. Although both work in this situation, the `&` is meant for concatenation, whereas the `+` is meant for addition.